# How to create a chrono::time_point object for a given calender date without using std::tm and mktime()

Tags: c++, c++14

I want to create a chrono::time_point object for a given date for example : 2020-03-06 22:48:01 where the format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS . I do not want to use  mktime() as it is not safe. Also I do not want to use any third party library such as date.

Comment: "*as it is not safe*" In what regard is it "not safe" for your needs?

Comment: @NicolBolas, QAC++ tool is giving a warning for me to use mktime()

Answer (score 1):

For C++11 and C++14, none of the chrono clocks have a specified epoch.  However one of them:  `system_clock` has an epoch that is the same among the three most popular implementations, gcc, llvm and VS.  This epoch is 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, excluding leap seconds.  This is also known as [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

While not guaranteed by the C++11/14 standards, you can program to this de-facto standard for `std::chrono::system_clock`.  But there are no portable epochs for `steady_clock` or `high_resolution_clock`.

Since you do not want to involve `std::tm`, you will have to write your own code to convert `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` to a count of seconds since the [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) epoch.  If `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` is a local time, you will also have to take into account the UTC offset, and the possibility that the UTC offset itself is a function of time for many time zones (i.e. daylight saving time).  If `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` is in string form, you will also need to parse these characters into integral types.

[Here are helpful formulas](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html) for converting the `YYYY-MM-DD` portion of your timestamp into a count of days since the [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) epoch.

> Slight change in my requirement is that, I am okay to use std::tm but not mktime(). Is there anyway to create std::chrono::time_point object?

If you are starting with data in a stream you could use `std::get_time` from `<iomanip>` to get the data into a `tm`.  Then there is a non-standard but popular [`timegm()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/timegm.3.html) that converts the `tm` to a `time_t`, neglecting timezones (the original timestamp is interpreted as UTC).  And then there is a `from_time_t` static member function of `system_clock` that will convert the `time_t` to `system_clock::time_point`.

Hmm... but [`timegm()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/timegm.3.html) probably qualifies as a 3rd party lib...

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Slight change in my requirement is that, I am okay to use std::tm but not mktime(). Is there anyway to create std::chrono::time_point object?

Comment: Added info on `timegm` to the answer.  Is your `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` UTC, or in some time zone?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS is in UTC. We are going with mktime() and to avoid timezone we add tm.tm_gmtoff which is giving same answer as timegm().

Answer (score 0):

All time points are relative to the epoch of the clock that generated them. But in C++14 (and C++17), clock epochs are implementation-specified. Every implementation's clocks have a time point, but there's no way to know what they are. And it makes no sense to ask, since times are all ultimately relative to some fixed date, so the epoch would have to itself be expressed relative to some other date.

So you must either use `std::mktime` or a 3rd party library. Or you could just write all the code yourself, but that code wouldn't be able to generate a time point from any particular clock unless it were coded in an implementation-specific fashion.